# A 2021 AIME problem (Number theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any positive integer $a, \sigma(a)$ denotes the sum of the positive integer divisors of $a$. Let $n$ be the least positive integer such that $\sigma(a^n)-1$ is divisible by $2021$ for all positive integers $a$. Find the sum of the prime factors in the prime factorization of $n$.

This is 2021 AIME I problem 14. I've already proved that n should be a multiple of 42 and 46 by Euler's Totient Theorem. However, I can't prove that n is also a multiple of 43 and 47.

The correct answer is 125. Could you give a full solution or some hints, please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divisor sum function is multiplicative, so if

$$a = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i},$$ then

$$\sigma(a^n) = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p^{\alpha_i n+1}-1}{p_i-1}.$$
This must have remainder $1$ mod $43$ and also mod $47.$ The only way to assure this is for this to be true for each multiplicand, so
$$p_i^{\alpha_i n+1} \equiv p_i \mod 43,$$ and
$$p_i^{\alpha_i n+1} \equiv p_i \mod 47,$$ *if* $p_i \notin \{43, 47\}.$
This is possible if $n$ is divisible by $42$ and by $46.$
We have a problem, however: what happens if $p_i=43$ (or $47$)? Well, then, both the numerator and the denominator are equal to $-1$ mod their respective prime, so the term equals $1$ mod their respective prime.
Now, what happens when $p_i \equiv 1 \mod 43?$ Then the geometric series summation cannot be used, and $\sigma(p_i^{\alpha_i n}) \equiv \alpha_i n +1 \mod 43$ (and similarly for $47$). So, this requires $n$ to be divisible by $43$ and $47$.
.

Comment: I thought there is a small mistake for the solution. For pi≡1 mod43, σ(p αini)≡ αin mod43 instead of ≡ αin+1 mod43 , since, the geometric sequence ends with ai*n th power of p. Right?

Comment: @HHY but it begins with the zeroth power.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Thanks!